# How is "repartition" related to parallelism in Spark and in what cases does it speed up the execution of operations?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, optimization

I'm starting to learn Spark, I've read a huge number of answers here, but I still don't understand.

The question is as follows: I read the data from the table and load it into the date frame as

```
spark.read.format("jdbc").....load()
```

then I need to write to parquet:

```
jdbcDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("compression", "snappy").save("test.parquet")
```

Does the parallelization method change if my table contains 20 million rows and 700 columns or if it is small? How do I know if I need parallelism at all or if Spark does it under the hood by itself? How can I make parallelism when writing data in parquet?

Please tell me where I can find information

I'm using this as an alternative to pandas and I need it to work fast. I don't understand how to parallelize the writing. I thought "repartition" was doing this, but after reading the articles I realized that this was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really just want to read a table via JDBC and immediately after that write it to parquet, you shouldn't have to use `.repartition()`. This is an expensive operation, as it requires data to be shuffled around in your Spark executors.

It seems like you just want to read your table in a parallelized fashion and the write it as a partitioned parquet file. If this is the case, each Spark executor can simply query a part of the original table and then write that part as a parquet partition.

You can achieve this by something like this:

```py
numPartitions = X
jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option(...) #a bunch of options like url/user/password
  .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
  .load()
```

So as you see, we specified a variable called `numPartitions` and used it in the `"numPartitions"` option in our read command. This will split up your table in X partitions and treat them in parallel.

Some considerations:

- Making this number higher will parallelize this operation until you've reached a `numPartitions` that is higher than the number of cores in your cluster. If you have 2 executors with 5 cores each, you can have max 10 partitions that are processed at the same time. If you specify a `numPartitions` that is higher, say 20, then your executors will first handle 10 partitions and do the other partitions as they finish the first ones.
- If you have a very large cluster (many CPU) available, be careful of specifying `numPartitions` that is too large: this will launch a bunch of requests in parallel and might overload the DB you're querying via JDBC.
- If you want to limit the number of parallel requests but have a very large table, so you still want a high `numPartitions` value, just limit the number of cores in your Spark cluster to a number that your DB can handle.

Once you've read in your data like this, you can simply write it to a parquet file like you specified:

```
jdbcDF.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("compression", "snappy").save("test.parquet")
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the answer) Tell me, please: I tried to put numPartitions = 60 in the parameter. However, it was slower than .repartition(100) when I'm working with a large table (20 million rows and 700 columns). But if it's a small table (1 million rows and 30 columns) . repartition only slows down the process. I have a total of 64 cores. Tell me, please, what could this be related to? I will also be very grateful if you recommend literature that clearly explains how spark works.

Comment: Hmm to properly answer that question we need more information, for example: where is the bottleneck? what does your query plan look like? what was the time difference between the trials? which exact code did your run? etc... But here on Stackoverflow, we like to keep our questions succinct and focused, and certainly not contain too much info in the comments. If you feel your original question has been answered, you can accept it. And if you liked it, you can upvote it. Don't hesitate to ask other questions!

Comment: But if `.repartition(100)` is faster your bottleneck might be in writing the parquet (really not sure, we need more info). You could try out `numPartitions` = 128 or another multiple of 64 to see if that speeds it up.